# Grouping MYSQL results by multiple columns and time span

Tags: mysql

How can I select one, most recent `NID`, per every 7 days, per `UID`, starting count back from today.

If today is July 11, the following table

```
+-----+------------+-----+
| NID |  timestamp | UID |
+-----+------------+-----+
|   1 | 1341719851 |   8 | //July 7
|   2 | 1341115051 |   8 | //July 1
|   3 | 1341547051 |   8 | //July 6
|   4 | 1341719851 |   8 | //July 8
|   5 | 1341979051 |   8 | //July 11
|   6 | 1341806251 |   9 | //July 9
|   7 | 1341460651 |   9 | //July 5
|   8 | 1341892651 |   9 | //July 10
+-----+------------+-----+
```

Will output this:

```
+-----+------------+-----+
| NID |  timestamp | UID |
+-----+------------+-----+
|   2 | 1341115051 |   8 | //July 1
|   5 | 1341979051 |   8 | //July 11
|   8 | 1341892651 |   9 | //July 10
+-----+------------+-----+
```

In the last 7 days, most recent `NID` for each user is `'5'` and `'8'`, in the prior 7 days, most recent `NID` is `'2'`, and so on...

I'm assuming, Group By will do the trick; but I don't have a clue where to start.

UPDATE

This is the query that worked, based on the top answer:

```
SELECT nid, timestamp, uid, weeks_ago
FROM (
    SELECT nid, timestamp, uid, FLOOR(
        (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()- timestamp)/604800
    ) weeks_ago
    FROM `table`
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC
) x
GROUP BY uid, weeks_ago
```

Comment: Is the `timestamp` column is a MySQL `TIMESTAMP` data-type?
Is this a *rolling* 7 days or is 7 days = a week? Are you wanting all results or just for the prior 7 days?

Comment: It's a Unix timestamp... I don't know if I understood you right. It's the rolling 7 days, i.e. 0-7 days from today, 8-14 days from today, 15-21... I need all results, not just the prior 7 days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select nid, max(timestamp), uid, weeks_ago
from (select nid, timestamp, uid, floor(datediff(now(), from_unixtime(timestamp))/7) weeks_ago
      from mytable) x
group by nid, uid, weeks_ago
```

Comment: Almost there. It outputs all columns, not grouping by weeks_ago per uid.

Comment: With a few tweaks to this answer (see my Update, above), the query worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
  select * from (
    (
      select nid, uid,timestamp,floor(datediff(now(), from_unixtime(timestamp))/7) as   weeks,from_unixtime(timestamp) as Dt from test t1 order by dt desc limit 0,2)
 Union
  (
  select nid, uid,timestamp,
  floor(datediff(now(), from_unixtime(timestamp))/7) as weeks,from_unixtime(timestamp) as Dt
 from test t2 group by weeks having weeks>0 order by dt asc limit 0,1
    )
     ) t4
```

May be this resolve your issue. Try this